# Insert into PHP string of HTML elements

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert a checkbox to a HTML form which is stored in a PHP string variable `$form`:

```
$form = "
  <form action='/action_page.php'>
     First name:<br>
     <input type='text' value='Mickey'><br>
     Last name:<br>
     <input type='text' name='lastname' value='Mouse'><br>
     <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>";

$checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='agree' required> I agree!";
```

Context: Wordpress `add_filter` callback gets the form and should add the checkbox at the end of the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to insert the checkbox in form but before submit button. You can use this

```
$form = "
  <form action='/action_page.php'>
     First name:<br>
     <input type='text' value='Mickey'><br>
     Last name:<br>
     <input type='text' name='lastname' value='Mouse'><br>
     <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  </form>";

$checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' name='agree' required> I agree!";
$form = str_replace("<input type='submit'", $checkbox."<input type='submit'", $form);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

Don't forget to put the ending tag 'form' after variable $checkbox

```
preg_replace('/<\/form>/', $checkbox.'</form>', $form);
```

Probably should have better ways to do it, but I don't know wordpress architecture to sugest a better solution.

Link of preg_replace: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php